# Can't run application with wine due to environment variable

Tags: wine, environment-variables

can someone help me to install right environment variable for Oracle?
Try to run app with wine and get error:

```
Initialization error
Oracle Client not properly installed

OracleHomeKey: 
OracleHomeDir:
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Wine will pass on the entire shell environment variable settings to the Windows environment variable space you can set this environment variable in the Linux shell.

Example for the bash shell :

```
export MYENVIRONMENTVAR=myenvironmentvarsetting
```

This will make sure your Windows program can access the `MYENVIRONMENTVAR` environment variable once you start your program using Wine. If you want to have MYENVIRONMENTVAR set permanently, then you can place the setting into `/etc/profile`, or also `~/.bashrc` when using bash.